# count rows in table on some condition

Tags: mysql

I have table, table B:

```
id   p.id    s.id
1      5       1
2      5       1 
3      5       2
4      5       2
5      5       3
```

The result looks like this:

```
s.id   count
1       2
2       2
3       1
```

I have tried:

```
Select count(s.id) from B group by s.id
```

But its not giving me the required result. I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple:

```
SELECT s.id
     , count(*) as COUNT
FROM B
GROUP BY s.id;
```